# Proof check: Problem 8, *Algorithm Design* by Skiener

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I have devised a proof for the following problem from the book *Algorithm Design* by S. S. Skiener (p. 28):

### Problem

[Using induction] Prove the correctness of the following algorithm for evaluating a polynomial $P(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 x + a_0$.

```
function horner(A, x):
    p = A[n]
    for i from n - 1 to 0:
        p = p * x + A[i]
    return p
```

### Proof

Let the integers $n \ge 0$ and $n \ge i \ge 0$.

It is simple to see that the algorithm "horner" of A (array of coefficients, namely, $A[i]=a_i$) and x calculates the polynomial in this way

$$
Q_i^n(x)=\begin{cases}a_n & n = i\\a_i + xQ_{i+1}^n(x) & n > i\end{cases}
$$

The conventional definition of the polynomial can be restated recursively like this

$$
P_i^n(x)=\begin{cases}a_n x^n & n = i \\ a_i x^i + P_{i + 1}^n (x) & n > i\end{cases}
$$

I will show you an example.

Let's have a polynomial defined with three coefficients $a_0, a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $n=2$.

$$\begin{align}Q_0^n(x) &= a_0 + x(a_1 + x(a_2))\\P_0^n(x) &= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2\end{align}$$

It's obvious that $Q_0^n(x) = P_0^n(x)$ for $n=2$.

So for this problem, I shall prove that $Q_0^n (x) = P_0^n (x)$ for all $n \ge 0$, which is to prove that "horner" of A and x is the same as $P(x)$.

#### $n=0$

Let's see how it is equal when $n = 0$.

$$\begin{align}Q_0^0(x) &= a_0\\P_0^0(x) &= a_0\end{align}$$

It's easy to see that they are equal.

#### $n>0$

I will use induction on $i$, with the base case being $n = i$, and $i$ decreasing by 1 all the way down to 0.

First let's see how $P_0^n (x) = Q_0^n (x)$. By expanding both sides like this

$$\begin{align}
P_0^n (x) &= a_0 + P_1^n (x)\\
Q_0^n (x) &= a_0 + x Q_1^n (x)
\end{align}$$

Notice that $P_1^n (x) = x Q_1^n (x)$ must be satisfied.

The key intuition is that $P_i^n (x) = x^i Q_i^n (x)$ must be satisfied.

This, I will prove.

Let's see the base case where $n = i$:

$$\begin{align}
P_n^n(x) &= x^n Q_n^n(x)\\
&= x^n a_n \\
&= P_n^n (x)
\end{align}$$

Now where $n > i$, assuming that $P_{i+1}^n (x) = x^{i+1} Q_{i+1}^n (x)$.

$$\begin{align}
P_i^n (x) &= x^i Q_i^n (x) \\
&= x^i [a_i + x Q_{i+1}^n (x)] \\
&= a_i x^i + x^{i + 1} Q_{i+1} ^ n (x) \\
&= a_i x^i + P_{i + 1} ^ n (x) \\
&= P_i^n (x)
\end{align}$$

So, it seems that for any given $n > 0$, $P_i^n(x) = x^i Q_i^n (x)$ for all $n \ge i \ge 0$.

That means $P_0^n(x) = Q_0^n (x)$.

### Conclusion

$Q_i^n (x)$ models the value of $p$ at the end of the for loop when $i$ is set to that value. This means that $Q_0^n (x)$ is our model for the return value of "horner" of A and x. Similarly, $P_i^n (x)$ represents the partial sum of the polynomial when terms $[i, n]$ have been added up, and $P_0^n (x)$ represents the value when all terms $[0, n]$ have been added up.

Since $P_0^n(x) = Q_0^n(x)$, we have the conclusion that the algorithm correctly calculates the polynomial, and we have shown it through mathematical induction on $i$, which is the same $i$ value in the for loop in the algorithm.

### Questions

1. Is this a correct use of mathematical induction?
2. How do I make my presentation better? Better as in smoother and more easy to understand for beginners like me.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't follow your proof exactly, but I think you are over-complicating things. Doing this by induction on $n$ where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial seems easier.

**Base Case**

$n=0$ so $P(x)=a_0$. So in the first line, $p=a_0$ and then the loop has no iterations so the function returns $a_0$ which is correct.

**Induction Step**

Assume the algorithm works for polynomials of degree $n$. We will then prove it works for polynomials of degree $n+1$.

Let

$P(x)=a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+a_{n}x^{n}+...+a_{0}$.

We can define a new polynomial:

$Q(x)=a_{n+1}x^{n}+a_{n}x^{n-1}+...+a_{1}$.

Note that $P(x)=Q(x) \times x + a_0$ (you can write out the algebra if you want) and $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

So, after $n$ times through the loop, the algorithm computes $Q$ correctly (by the induction hypothesis). On loop iteration $n+1$ the algorithm then computes $Q(x) \times x + a_0$ which is $P(x)$.